# Show that $\int_A f\, dV=f(a)\text{vol}(A)$ for some $a\in A$ if $A$ is bounded, path-connected and $\partial A$ has measure zero.

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-sum

Let $A$ be a bounded, path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\partial A$ has measure zero. Let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, continuous function. Show that there exists $a\in A$ such that $I:=\int_A f\, dV=f(a)\text{vol}(A)$.

My attempt:

Let $R$ be a rectangle containing $A$. Let $\bar{f}=f$ on $A$ and $\bar{f}=0$ otherwise. Let $m=\inf f(A)$ and $M=\sup f(A)$. We want to show that $m\le I/\text{vol}(A)\le M$. We first attempt to show that $I\le M\text{vol}(A)$. It suffices to show that for any partition $P$ of $R$,
$$ U(\bar{f},P)=\sum_{Q\in P}\sup \bar{f}(Q) \text{vol}(Q) \le M \sum_{Q\in P}\inf 1_A(Q)\text{vol}(Q)=M\cdot L(1_A,P).$$
For each $Q\in P$, if $Q\subset A$, then $\sup\bar{f}(Q)=\sup f(Q)\le\sup f(A)\le M\inf 1_A(Q)$. However, when $Q$ crosses the boundary, we no longer have this easy inequality. I am struggling on how to apply either that $\partial A$ has measure zero or that $A$ is path-connected here.

Also, after we have shown that $m\le I/\text{vol}(A)\le M$, if it happens that $I/\text{vol}(A)=M$ or $m$, how should one apply the path-connectedness here? We do not have compact domain here.

Comment: Are you really supposed to prove this from first principles? You cannot just make use of $\text{vol}(A) = \int_A 1\,dV$, and the theorem $f \le g \implies \int f \le \int g$?

Comment: As for where $A$ is path-connected comes in, notice how you talk about $Q$ crossing a boundary. In one dimension, this result follows from the intermediate value theorem.  Look at why, and how you can leverage that in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments, note that $m\text{vol}(A)=\int_A m\le\int_A f \le \int_A M=M\text{vol}(A)$.

If $\text{vol}(A)=0$, then the inequalities imply $\int_A f=0$, which then implies $f=0$ on $A$ because $f$ is continuous.
If $\int_A f=\int_A m$, then we have $f(x)=m$ for all continuity point $x$ of $f$.
Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f=m$ on $A$, so $\int_A f=f(a)\text{vol}(A)$ for any $a\in A$.
The same holds if $\int_A f=\int_A M$.

Suppose $\text{vol}(A)\neq 0$ and let $y_0:=\int_A f/\text{vol}(A)\not\in\{m,M\}$.
Let $X:=f(A)\cap (-\infty,y_0)$.
Since $y_0>m$, $X$ is nonempty, so $f(a_1)<y_0$ for some $a_1\in A$.
Similarly, $f(a_2)>y_0$ for some $a_2\in A$.
Since $A$ is path-connected, there exists a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to A$ such that $g(0)=a_1$ and $g(1)=a_2$.
Then $f\circ g$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$,
so the intermediate value theorem guarantees that $(f\circ g)(t)=y_0$ for some $t\in[0,1]$.
Choose $a:=g(t)$ and we have $f(a)=y_0$, as desired.

The condition that the measure of $\partial A$ is zero is there simply for the integrability over $A$.